# Show Users in a loop - but even if they have no posts

Tags: wordpress, loops

I need a normal loop to show users (with custom meta fields etc.) so i have this code that shows a loop. But i need to show users that have no posts, too.

```
<?php
                $authors=get_users();
                $i=0;
                //get all users list
                foreach($authors as $author){
                    $authorList[$i]['id']=$author->data->ID;
                    $authorList[$i]['name']=$author->data->display_name;
                    $i++;
                }
            ?>
            <ul>
                <?php 
                foreach($authorList as $author){
                    $args=array(
                            'showposts'=>1,
                            'author'=>$author['id'],
                            'caller_get_posts'=>1
                           );
                    $query = new WP_Query($args);
                    if($query->have_posts() ) {
                        while ($query->have_posts()){
                            $query->the_post();
                ?>
                <li>


                 <h2><?php echo $author['name']; ?></h2>
                 <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> <?php echo get_the_title(); ?> </a>
                </li>
                <?php
                    }
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing it now with "WP_User_Query", it works way better. example: http://blog.shaunscovil.com/post/55272793162/the-difference-between-get-user-meta-and-get-userdata